# Inside hvac unit rattles at night

Tags: air-conditioning

My inside hvac unit believe it or not only rattles at night I know that's crazy.  whenever I remove the filter it seems to suck in more air and stopes rattling the moment I place the filter back the rattling begins. Mind you the air filter is a new filter. Crazy thing is that throughout the morning and evening there is no noise or rattling only at night. The rattling sounds so loud that you would think the motor is going to fall off, but again only at night . Has anyone had this kind of problem before?

Comment: Are you saying the filter was rattling or the rattling was coming from somewhere else in the ductwork or cabinet and increasing the airflow by removing the filter stopped it?

Comment: Sorry if my post did not make since , but the motor or blower seems to rattle a lot at night not sure why. Everytime I remove the airfilter the rattling aka motor seems to stop rattling. As soon as I place the filter back on it begins to rattle again. I wish I could upload a video so that you can see what I mean

Comment: The only at night part is truly bizarre. What is the brand/model number of your furnace? You could post to youtube or some other service and then post the link here. I wonder if it runs at some other speed at night for some reason and hits a resonant frequency of the cabinet.

Comment: It's a carrier 8000 , yes I know it gets annoying at night hearing all that rattling going on.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kX_RnDtaoaI I just uploaded the video on YouTube

Comment: Does just a single LED from the control board light up the peep hole that much? Are there any trouble codes blinking on the LEDs?

Comment: Not that I know of , that light has always been lit as far as I know it.

Comment: Does it seem to start/stop at certain times or just randomly through the night?

Comment: It seems to start rattling around 8 830 at night and last all night whenever it is running and stop rattling in the morning around 7am very bazaar. So right now it's 732 and working just fine. We shall see in a few more minutes how it sounds. This has been going on for months now.

Comment: Peer in the hole and see if any of the lights blink. You may need to watch for 15 seconds or so and they may not be easy to see as they can be off to the side. You should have a label with trouble codes on or in the cabinet if you haven't d/l the manual. Flip the disconnect that should be on the cabinet unless the breaker box is within sight to kill power to the unit and open the cabinet and do the checks Ed suggested. Also verify the cage spins freely with no wobble.

Comment: Ok thanks will do. Just thinking out loud , if a code was there why would this only effect the blower at night and not all through out the day ?

Comment: Ok so the light stays on when it's off and on. my panel it states continuous off - check for 115vac at L1 and 24 vac at sec -1 , continuous on - control has 24vac power , rapid flashing - line voltage polarity reversed

Comment: Have no idea why only at night. Clutching at straws at this point. So everything seems tight and no odd noises when you spun the cage? Seems like it must be related to airflow or "friction" but don't know why that would change so consistently at night.

Comment: I know very bazaar , I have a ac guy coming out to see if he can see anything that I am missing

Comment: Please post the answer if he solves it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it would be diferent at night unless you have a multi speed fan. Or the house is opened up or closed more. If a direct drive check the motor mount bolts to make they are secure and the squirrel cage to verify the bolts are not loose. If a belt drive the belt may need tighting checking the pulley on the motor and squirrel cage also would be my checks.

Comment: Yea that's why I don't know what could be going on it doesn't rattle during the day just at night I have a video of it if only o could post it on here

Comment: If it starts and stops at regular intervals, like day / night, it sounds like the thermostat. It needs to be re-programmed. Maybe it's calling for more heat at night and the second stage fan kicks in.